# Issue with gradle composite build

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin, kotlin-multiplatform

I have updated my kotlin multi platform project from android gradle plugin 4.2.1 and kotlin 1.4.32 to android gradle 4.2.1 and kotlin 1.5.10.
I have also updated the gradle plugin from 6.7.1 to 6.8.3. But after this update getting below error in Android Studio 4.2.1 during gralde sync.

I searched about this error but could be able to find the much details about `AnalyticsService`

```
* Exception is:
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Failed to create service 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.AnalyticsService_875fdcc1-2c6d-43e7-babe-40606c3a66e6'.
Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.AnalyticsService.
Cannot query the value of this property because it has no value available.
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.addBuildModels(ProjectImportAction.java:259)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:127)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:42)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.InternalBuildActionAdapter.execute(InternalBuildActionAdapter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionRunningListener.runAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:134)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionRunningListener.buildFinished(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:119)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor336.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Any small pointer will be helpful.

Comment: It seems there is known issue and will get delivered in Android studio 4.2.2 release.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173805889

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have checked above mentioned gradle composite build issue with **Android Studio version 4.2.2** and this issue has been fixed.